automatically create a new sheet
How to automatically create a new sheet in Google Sheets based on criteria in the Master sheet?
If the status is ‘CLOSE’ (see column C), then automatically create a new sheet based on the Sales Name.

Here is the link that can be worked on :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pMZQhhQcWVzh-1uQsfhXZHuNWWBxj8gfsEOQf54lRY8/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Can you help me create the formula using Apps Script?

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

create a new sheet based on the Sales Name. Just to clarify; do you mean insert a new sheet AND name the new sheet with the value in the adjacent "Name Sales" column? Can you help me create the formula using Apps Script? What sort of help do you want? some advice; a specific issue that you're having trouble with; not sure how to trigger the script?

Create a new sheet based on cell value.
I integrated a conditional Statement to check if the data in "STATUS" column is set to "CLOSED" and used an onEdit Trigger to make it automatic.
You can try the following code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('MASTER');
  var range = e.range;

  if (sheet.getName() === 'MASTER' && range.getColumn() === 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var nameSales = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue().trim(); 
    var status = range.getValue(); 
    
    if (status === 'CLOSE' && nameSales) {
      var sheetName = nameSales;
      var newSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName); 

      var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      var rowData = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

      if (!newSheet) {
        newSheet = e.source.insertSheet(sheetName); 
        newSheet.appendRow(headers); 
      }

      if (newSheet.getLastRow() === 1) { 
        newSheet.appendRow(rowData); 
      }
    }
  }
}

Sample output:

Kindly be aware of the following:

You must run the code at least once(upon pasting the code) to accept the authorization before creating a trigger
The code is purely based on editing the values of the dataset to "CLOSED"
onEdit trigger has a limitation, you must manually set the status to "CLOSED" for the code to create a new sheet with the data included.

REFERENCE:

Conditional Statement
onEdit()


This code is only a suggestion based on how I understand your question including the sample sheet that you have provided. This may have some limitations.

Feel free to try it on your end and let me know how it turns out.

Using a reserved name for simple triggers, in this case, onEdit, is a bad practice for an installable trigger handler function: it will be fired twice.
